# Выделение памяти для типа char*

Tags: c++, c, char, malloc, new

Немного не понимаю для чего приводить к типу `char*`.

Например выделяем память `char *ptr=(char*)malloc(10)` Читал из поста про Си стиль,почему раньше использовали приведение в `char`,но мне не понятно все равно, какой в этом толк сейчас? Ну,т.е. почему обязательно в `char*`,мы же можем использовать тип `void*`,да даже любой тип,но почти во всех исходниках вижу тот же `char*`.
Или же `char *ptr = new char(10)`.

`char*` на столько универсален? тот же `void*` разве не логичнее брать? для чего `char*` использовать в выделении памяти,если после внутри значения куча символов._.

Comment: Вы не ошиблись? Может, к типу `char*`? И, кстати, такое приведение нужно в С++, но не в С.

Comment: @Harry да,имел ввиду char*,спасибо. Видимо в слове "Немного", не лишнее. Нифигэ не понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Немного не понимаю для чего приводить к типу char*.

Я уже даже отвечал на этот вопрос. В си очень много построено на том, что нужно уметь работать с арифметикой указателей. Каждый раз, когда указатель увеличивается на 1, его реальный адрес под капотом увеличивается на размер типа, куда указывает этот указатель.

то есть, если у нас указатель на int

```
int * a = ....
```

то, сделав такое

```
a++;
```

сам указатель (его значение в виде числа) увеличится скорее всего на 4 (так как sizeof(int) == 4 в многих случаях, с которыми столкнется обычный программист, правда на ардуинке это 2).

Если же мы берем `void*`, то тут чуточку сложнее - sizeof(void) не определен по определению. Поэтому для него адресная арифметика не работает. А без этого в си ничего почти не сделать. То есть, с си  с указателем на void* может только передать куда то дальше (например, в функцию копирования) привести к какому то типу или освободить память. и все. А записывать сохранять значения сильно сложно (без приведений типов).

> Читал из поста про Си стиль,почему раньше использовали приведение в char,но мне не понятно все равно, какой в этом толк сейчас? Ну,т.е. почему обязательно в char*,мы же можем использовать тип void*,да даже любой тип,но почти во всех исходниках вижу тот же char*. Или же char *ptr = new char(10).

о, тут намешано. В си можно можно писать `char *ptr = malloc(10);` и не нужно специально делать приведений. Компилятор прекрасно понимает, что void* умеет в char*. А также упоминается в этом куске и с++ способ выделения памяти, но там все строго типизировано, `new char[10]` возвращает именно указатель на `char*`.

> char* на столько универсален? тот же void* разве не логичнее брать? для чего char* использовать в выделении памяти,если после внутри значения куча символов.

Тут все ещё интереснее. у char тяжелая судьба. Он с одной стороны представляет байт, минимальную адресуемую единицу (ведь в плюсах sizeof(char) строго 1), а с другой стороны представляет символ, а массив символов это самый распространённый способ представит строку. Из за этого я думаю и все беды. Плюс ещё неопределенность со знаковостью... Он в с++ вводят [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), но как по мне, то это очень и очень кривое решение.

Эх, нужно было делать тип char и byte изначально. и при выводе не было бы проблем. Но уже давно поздно. Это насколько внедрилось во все сферы, что не выпилить это.

Но не смотря на это, char продолжает быть одним из самых востребованных и популярных типов.

Но создатели стандарта не унимаются. Например, есть такая проблема, как каламбур типизации. Если очень грубо, то не всякий указатель на один тип можно взять и привести к указателю на другой тип и потом безопасно использовать. Но вот `char*` и `void*` стоят в сторонке. им много чего позволено.

Подсумируем.

- `void*` использовать сложно, потому что результат `sizeof(void)` не определен, а это мешает работать арифметике указателей и массивам.
- `char` это не только символы, но и представление байтов, хотя все от этого пытаются открещиваться руками и ногами  на публике, но продолжают использовать.
- `char` может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым и с этим ничего нельзя поделать. `unsigned char` и `signed char` похоже два типа сиротушки.

Comment: Т.е. используют `char` т.к. для него работает адресная арифметика и он самый маленький по размеру?А символы что внутри в выделении памяти это просто особенность этого типа,а на деле там свободное пространство для заполнения чего-либо.   Я верно понял?

Comment: Интересно, вот раз `char` это символы (однобайтовые), то как же в C/C++ работают с многобайтовыми символами `unicode`? )  Там наверное всё ещё запущеннее.

Comment: то, что внутри char видны символы - это просто представление этих байтов.

Comment: @CrazyElf а тут разные методы. Если это utf8 - то несколько char подряд. Или wchar_t (оно умеет двохбайтовые) или в некоторых случаях даже int

Comment: о, и тут минусаторов подвезли. Товарищи минусаторы, если Вы ставите минус, то хоть напишите, что Вам не нравится. Иначе Ваш минус абсолютно бесполезный.

Comment: *Я уже даже отвечал на этот вопрос* — если это было на этом сайте, то, наверно, стоило хотя бы привести эту ссылку.